# Upsert multiple rows in PostgreSQL with psycopg2 and errors logging

Tags: python, postgresql, performance, psycopg2

I'm writing an application that connects to database and upserts multiple rows, it creates SAVEPOINT for every row, so I can rollback without breaking a transaction, if there is a mistake, and commits every 500 rows.

The problem is that it works extremely slow for remote database connections (postgresql database on DigitalOcean droplet) - it took about 35 minutes to process 1000 rows, when it was only 7 second with local database (which is also not quite fast, but ok).

I found post about upserting using one cursor.execute(), like [here](https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2015/04/27/inserting-lots-of-data-into-a-remote-postgres-efficiently/), but how should I catch errors if using this trick? Or what else should I do to make it work faster? Here is my code:

```
self.connection = psycopg2.connect(self.connection_settings)
self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
for record in dbf_file:
    self.cursor.execute("SAVEPOINT savepoint;")
    try:
        self.send_record(record, where_to_save=database)
        self.count += 1
        self.batch_count += 1
        if self.batch_count >= BATCH_COUNT_MAX:
            self.connection.commit()
            self.cursor.close()
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            self.batch_count = 0
    except Exception:
        self.cursor.execute("ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT savepoint;")
        self.save_error(traceback.format_exc())
        self.error_count += 1
        self.batch_count += 1

        if self.batch_count == BATCH_COUNT_MAX:
            self.connection.commit()
            self.cursor.close()
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            self.batch_count = 0
    else:
        if self.batch_count != 0:
```

Comment: Several things you could do: 1. Don't continually close and re-open the connection; 2. Extract groups of records locally and send them all with a single prepared statement; 3. Increase the size of the batches you are using; and 4. Use the `copy_expert()` command instead.

Comment: @rd_nielsen
1) I don't re-open the connection (creating new cursor != new connection, right?)
2) But what if there is a mistake with one record in group? (Table has some foreign key constraints)  Then all records in group will not be added?
3) Okey, I'll try with bigger ones

Comment: Switch to `INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE ...`. Your current model is always going to perform terribly, it's doing multiple round-trips per row. If you can't use 9.5 upsert support, then you can improve it by using a stored proc to at least reduce round trips. See the manual for an example upsert proc.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are already using files, I'd suggest:

1. Make those files CSV (500 or what have you rows each)
2. Upload them to the server (scp/ftp/rsync)
3. Use psycopg's [`copy_from()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#copy)

This way you will likely eliminate unneeded network overhead.